# Javascript - how to replace the play track with another clip name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jplayer

I need to play `clip1`, `clip2`, `clip3` not as autoplay and not as shuffle, but later depending on some other logical condition.

The first clip1 is always working like this.

But how can i now tell jplayer to play `clip2`? do i have to remove the `#jquery_jplayer_1` div?

if i remove it then its not working at all, because `m4v:` still holding only one url to the `clip1`

how do you change the clip1 url `"http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"`  to clip3 (others.m4v) or clip2 (etcetc.m4v) within Javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
      ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
          title: "Big Buck Bunny",
          m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v",
        });
      },
      swfPath: "/js",
      supplied: "m4v, ogv",
      cssSelectorAncestor: "",
      cssSelector: {
        play: "#play",
      },
      size: {
        width: "320px",
        height: "180px"
      }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <button id="play">play</button>
  </p>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pl =[];
pl[0] = {m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"};
pl[1] = {m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"};

function play1() {
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", pl[0]);
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer('play');
}

function play2() {
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", pl[1]);
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer('play');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    supplied: "m4v, webm",
    size: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
    }
  });

});
</script>

<button onclick="play1();">play1</button>
<button onclick="play2();">play2</button>

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" ></div>
```